# RegEx to match string between two strings in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

Here is my sample data:

> Option failonnomatch on
>   Option batch on
>   Option confirm Off
>   open sftp://username:password@host.name.net:22 hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024
>   00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00"
>
> get File*.txt \local\path\Client\File.txt
>   mv File*.txt  /remote/archive/
>
> close
>   exit

I would like to create a powershell script to extract pieces of information out of this text file.

List of items I need:

- Username
- Password
- Host
- Port
- ssh key
- File Name
- Local Path
- Remote Path

I'm hoping that if I learn how to do a couple of these, the method will be applicable to all items. I attempted to extract the ssh key with the following powershell/regex:

```
$doc -match '(?<=hostkey=")(.*)(?=")'
```

*$doc being the sample data*

but it appears to be returning the whole line. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If their all key/value like that, just use `(?<=\bkey=")([^"]*)(?=")`  Or, you could do a global match using `(?<=\b\w+=")([^"]*)(?=")`

Comment: Your command will ony return $true/$false. To return a value you need to evaluate the $Matches collection. Also to what file do you refer? [edit] your question to contain some sample data.

Comment: what part of the last line is the "file" and what part is the "path"? the `File*.txt` looks like a file specification. the next part seems to be the full file name. i presume you want that broken into `\SERVER\Path\Client` & `File.txt` but i'm unsure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If `-match` is returning a *whole line***, the implication is that **the LHS of your `-match` operation is an *array*,** which in turn suggests that you used `Get-Content` *without `-Raw`*, which yields the input as an *array* of *lines*, **in which case `-match` acts as a *filter***.

Instead, read your file as a single, multi-line string with `Get-Content -Raw`; **with a *scalar* LHS, 
`-match` then returns a `[bool]`**, and the **results of the matching operation are reported in automatic variable `$Matches`** (a hashtable whose `0` entry contains the overall match, `1` what the 1st capture group matched, ...):

```
# Read file as a whole, into a single, multi-line string.
$doc = Get-Content -Raw file.txt 

if ($doc -match '(?<=hostkey=")(.*)(?=")') {
   # Output what the 1st capture group captured
   $Matches[1]
}
```

With your sample input, the above yields
`ssh-rsa 1024 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00`

---

You can then extend the approach to capture multiple tokens, in which case I suggest **using *named* capture groups** (`(?<name>...)`); the following example uses such named capture groups to extract several of the tokens of interest:

```
if ($doc -match '(?<=sftp://)(?<username>[^:]+):(?<password>[^@]+)@(?<host>[^:]+)'){
  # Output the named capture-group values.
  # Note that index notation (['username']) and property
  # notation (.username) can be used interchangeably.
  $Matches.username
  $Matches.password
  $Matches.host
}
```

With your sample input, the above yields:

```
username
password
host.name.net
```

You can extend the above to capture *all* tokens of interest.
Note that `.` by default doesn't match `\n` (newline) characters.

---

#### Optional reading: Using the `x` ([`IgnoreWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#Whitespace)) option to make regexes more readable:

Extracting that many tokens can result in a complex regex that is hard to read, in which case the `x` (`IgnoreWhiteSpace`) regex option, can help (as an inline option, `(?x)` at the start of the regex):

```
if ($doc -match '(?x)
    (?<=sftp://)(?<username>[^:]+)
    :(?<password>[^@]+)
    @(?<host>[^:]+)
    :(?<port>\d+)
    \s+hostkey="(?<sshkey>.+?)"
    \n+get\ File\*\.txt\ (?<localpath>.+)
    \nmv\ File\*\.txt\ (?<remotepath>.+)
  '){
    # Output the named capture-group values.
    $Matches.GetEnumerator() | ? Key -ne 0
}
```

Note how the whitespace used for making the regex more readable (spreading it across multiple lines) is *ignored* while matching, whereas whitespace to be matched in the input must be *escaped* (e.g., to match a single space, `\`  or `[ ]`, or `\s` to match any whitespace char.)

With your sample input, the above yields the following:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
host                           host.name.net
localpath                      \local\path\Client\File.txt
port                           22
sshkey                         ssh-rsa 1024 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
remotepath                     /remote/archive/
password                       password
username                       username
```

Note that the reason the capture groups are out of order is that `$Matches` is a *hash table* (of type [`[hashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable)), whose key enumeration order is an implementation artifact: no particular enumeration order is guaranteed.

However, random access to capture groups works just fine; e.g., `$Matches.port` will return `22`.

Comment: I like this method as the regex seems to make a little more sense but I'm getting stuck when I go down to grab the file name. I think it's because I'm moving to a new line but I'm not sure how to include that in the regex. Thank you.

`(?<=sftp://)(?<username>[^:]+):(?<password>[^@]+)@(?<host>[^:]+):(?<port>[^-]+) -hostkey="(?<sshkey>[^"]+)(?<=get )(?<filename>[^/])`

Comment: @MichaelSPalatsi: You need to match intervening whitespace as well (and, as stated, by default `.` doesn't match `\n` (newlines)). Please see my update for using the `IgnoreWhiteSpace` regex option to make complex expressions more manageable.

Comment: Awesome! That will certainly clean things up. I believe I have one last question. Say I have a group of files and I intend on using this regex against all of those files BUT in some files, one of my groupings is likely to not match anything. How can I handle that?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MichaelSPalatsi. As for your follow-up question: that's hard to answer in the abstract. I suggest you create a _new question_ that focuses just on that problem with specific examples. Feel free to ping me here once you have done so, and I'm happy to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

this uses named matches with flags set to `singleline, multiline, case insensitive` and then uses `$Matches.MatchName` to get the items into a custom object.

```
# fake reading in a text file as one string
#    in real life, use Get-Content -Raw
$InStuff = @'
open sftp://username:password@host.name.net:22 hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00"

get File*.txt \SERVER\Path\Client\File.txt
'@

$Null = $InStuff -match '(?smi).+//(?<UserName>.+):(?<Password>.+)@(?<HostName>.+):(?<Port>.+) hostkey="(?<SshKey>.+)".+get .+ (?<FullFileName>\\.+)$'

[PSCustomObject]@{
    UserName = $Matches.UserName
    Password = $Matches.Password
    Port = $Matches.Port
    SshKey = $Matches.SshKey
    PathName = Split-Path -Path $Matches.FullFileName -Parent
    FileName = Split-Path -Path $Matches.FullFileName -Leaf
    }
```

output ...

```
UserName : username
Password : password
Port     : 22
SshKey   : ssh-rsa 1024 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
PathName : \SERVER\Path\Client
FileName : File.txt
```

Comment: It's an effective solution (+1), but if you provide a complete solution that is specific to the OP's exact scenario _without addressing the misconceptions implied by the question_ (around how `-match` works),
you'll make the _OP_ very happy, but future readers with similar misconceptions - but different scenarios - won't necessarily benefit.

Comment: @mklement0 - i see what you mean ... i took the mention of "as one string" covered that idea. yours is far more detailed on the subject. i'll try to keep that in mind. [*grin*]

Comment: Hi Lee,
I failed to mention I have additional lines preceding and following the given sample. How can I accommodate those lines? Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelSPalatsi - you will need to add a _complete_ text to your original post so that folks can have a realistic sample to code against. if the text is too long, post it to Pastebin or Gist.GitHub and add a link to it into your OP.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That makes sense. Sorry, I'm new. :) I've updated the OP.

Comment: @MichaelSPalatsi - change the end of the regex pattern from `)$'` to `)mv.+$'`. that will stop the capture @ the `mv` command.