# Regex in PowerShell returning more info than necessary

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm capturing output and doing a regex on it to figure out what number comes after the string 'script'. I'm using the regex 'script\d\d' but it's returning more output than what I'm expected.

Example of the result output:

```
value:
- code: ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded
  displayStatus: Provisioning succeeded
  level: Info
  message: ''
  time: null
- code: ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded
  displayStatus: Provisioning succeeded
  level: Info
  message: "At C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\1.1.3\\\
    Downloads\\script11.ps1:9 char:98\n+ ... \\Microsoft.Net\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\\
    Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll\" >\n+                                        \
    \                                  ~\nMissing file specification after redirection\
    \ operator.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:13 char:9\n+             using System;\n+     \
    \             ~\nMissing using directive\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:13 char:4\n+             using System;\n+     \
    \        ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements in\
    \ a script.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:14 char:9\n+             using System.Reflection;\n\
    +                  ~\nMissing using directive\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:14 char:4\n+             using System.Reflection;\n\
    +             ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements\
    \ in a script.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:15 char:9\n+             using System.Diagnostics;\n\
    +                  ~\nMissing using directive\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:15 char:4\n+             using System.Diagnostics;\n\
    +             ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements\
    \ in a script.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:16 char:9\n+             using System.Runtime.InteropServices;\n\
    +                  ~\nMissing using directive\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:16 char:4\n+             using System.Runtime.InteropServices;\n\
    +             ~~~~~\nA 'using' statement must appear before any other statements\
    \ in a script.\nAt C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:17 char:9\n+             using Microsoft.Build.Framework;\n\
    +                  ~\nMissing using directive\nNot all parse errors were reported.\
    \  Correct the reported errors and try again.\n    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError:\
    \ (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingFileSpecification\n\
    \ "
  time: null
```

Example of the regex output

`$result -match 'script\d\d'`

```
    Downloads\\script11.ps1:9 char:98\n+ ... \\Microsoft.Net\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:13 char:9\n+             using System;\n+     \
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:13 char:4\n+             using System;\n+     \
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:14 char:9\n+             using System.Reflection;\n\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:14 char:4\n+             using System.Reflection;\n\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:15 char:9\n+             using System.Diagnostics;\n\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:15 char:4\n+             using System.Diagnostics;\n\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:16 char:9\n+             using System.Runtime.InteropServices;\n\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:16 char:4\n+             using System.Runtime.InteropServices;\n\
    1.1.3\\Downloads\\script11.ps1:17 char:9\n+             using Microsoft.Build.Framework;\n\
```

I'm only trying to capture the first iteration of the string "script" and whatever numbers comes after it, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: when you put a _collection_ on the left of many operators, PoSh will give you every collection item that the operator works with. `-eq` will give you those that equal the thing on the right. in your example, the `-match` will give you every line line that matches the pattern on the right. if you want only the 1st item, wrap the code in `()` and select the `[0]` item. [*grin*]

Comment: Please don't post small variations of what is essentially the same question. The only notable difference was that you didn't make it clear in the linked post that you only wanted the _first_ match - something that adding `; break` to the answer there - which is otherwise virtually identical - could have addressed. Instead of providing feedback there, you decided to create a duplicate question, which creates both unnecessary noise and wasted effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears `$result` is an array of lines, `-match` will return the lines that match your regex pattern. If you match against a single item rather than a collection, the `$matches` automatic variable will contain the matched string and any corresponding capture groups.

Therefore, in order to use `-match` this way, you need to process `$result` line by line. My preference would be to use the `switch` statement to effectively do the same thing.

```
switch -Regex ($result) {
    'script(\d+)' { $matches.1 ; break }
}
```

The break statement will stop processing matches after the first match is found.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

Result output to output.txt

```
# Read file as a whole, into a single, multi-line string. Prevents -match acting as a filter
$z = gc -raw output.txt
[regex]::Match($z,'script(\d+)').Groups[1].value
```

Results:

```
11
```

[Understanding Regex capture groups in PowerShell](https://adamtheautomator.com/regex-capture-groups-powershell/)

[If -match is returning a whole line (acting as a filter) use gc -raw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53328805/8826818)

`Get-Content` without `-Raw` returns an array of lines, and passing an array as the first argument to `.Match()` causes PowerShell to stringify it by concatenating the array elements with spaces, which can yield false positives; e.g., `[regex]::Match(('C:\Program', 'Files'), 'Program Files')` matches.

.NET regex is case-sensitive and PowerShell regex is case-insensitive by default.